# Problems using pstool with miktex

Tags: miktex, pstool

I am recently writing my thesis.

To get nice plots I use the matlabfrag-option in Matlab to create a .tex and .eps File. 
With the help of \psfragfig I include the Matlab-Figure in Latex.

I use texnic center with miktex.

Sometimes I have to continue writing on a latop whicht doesn't allow some installations. Therefore I am using MikTex Portable while TeXnic Center is installed on the laptop.

While compiling I get this message:

[image]

The exact same code does compile perfecty fine on the laptop where both miktex and texnic center are installed. This Error does only appear while using miktex portable.

I am using this command in Texnic Center for the compiler:
-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode --enable-write18 "%wm"

Has anyone already encoutered this problem too?

I already did some testing and could reproduce this error on another laptop while switching from miktex installed to miktex portable and back.

Comment: [crosspost](http://golatex.de/pstool-funktioniert-nicht-t16972.html)